# I want to download theme files from server and change UI of my iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, themes

I have requirements for my iOS (Swift) application from my Client.

1: I want to implement multiple themes in the application. Users can select any theme from the list and the application changes its colours, image styles, Fonts etc. (Just think about the Android themes application that change everything of the Android UI i.e App icons style, fonts background colour etc)

2: Some themes would be downloaded from our server i.e we will download a file from the server with a specific set of Colours, fonts, image styles etc and our iOS application changes its UI accordingly.

Point 2 is the main thing that I want to implement in the iOS application.

Can anyone help me how i can implement this?
Because i looked many Github repo's and Stackoverflow's questions but none of them are matched with my requirements.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please follow this site's [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). There is no reference on how you are working this out. It might be your English, but it looks like you are asking for someone to develop your app.

Comment: Hi @HunterLion i updated the question. Hopefully it is more clear now.